# how to replace an integer from a column for another integer contained in another file, python or awk

Tags: python, file, replace, awk

I have 2 big files.In the first file I have a column with integers which need to be replaced by other integers contained in another big file (2nd file)

```
1st FILE

123
124
125
126
127

2nd FILE

123    200
124    201
126    203
127    204
```

The 2nd file contains one column with almost every integer of the 1st file, and a second column with the integers used to replace. So, if the integer is in both files, replace that integer by the one in the second column, same line.

```
DESIRED OUTPUT FILE

200
201
203
204
```

Both input files are very big and have other columns and headers beginning by `#`

Comment: yeah sorry.. you are right. Already edited

Comment: Mmm I see but isn't 2nd column of 2nd file == Desired output file?

Comment: so what do you try ? where is your snippet.

Comment: nono.. because the first file has a lot more columns and information... and I just want to replace that column and keeping the rest the same

Comment: @ÀngelBa Out of curiosity. Are the numbers in "1st FILE" and the first column in "2nd FILE" strictly increasing? And, are there repeated values in "1st FILE"?

Comment: are your files sorted ?

Comment: How do the files _actually_ look like, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {if ($1 in a) {$1=a[$1]}}1' f2 f1
```

Given an extended input file `f1` it returns:

```
200
12345
201
125
203
204
133
```

Note the file `f1` I used is has some more records, so that there are some that do not match in the `f2`:

```
$ cat f1
123
12345
124
125
126
127
133
```

### Update

> This is very fast but it stills print the line if there is no match of
>   both integers, and I don't want that... how would that be in that
>   case??

If you just want to print the matches, then use:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a {$1=a[$1]; print}' f2 f1
200
201
203
204
```

Comment: This is very fast but it stills print the line if there is no match of both integers, and I don't want that... how would that be in that case??

Comment: ok, but now only prints the column, and not the rest of the line... it is possible??

Comment: It is a bit tiring to be testing something with proper input data. It is showing the desired output based on your sample input. If you want to print more fields, tell us how they look like; probably `print a[$1], $2`, etc, will make it.

Comment: exactly.. I am deeply sorry, you have reason... I wanted to make the question easy but I didn't succed. Thanks, it worked! :)

Comment: `{if ($1 in a) {print a[$1]}}` -> `$1 in a {print a[$1]}` but I THINK from reading the OPs comments what she actually wanted was `$1 in a {$1=a[$1]; print}`. It's always fun to work on a problem and then have th OP tell you "oh but my input doesn't actually look like the sample I posted". Just reinforces the tru-ism that half the people you meet are of below average intelligence :-).

Comment: Hahaha, your comments are always something to read and keep, @EdMorton . I indicated to use `print a[$1], $2...` in my last comment to the OP (is "he", as Àngel is masculine in Catalan :D), but your version is way better, so I am updating my answer with your suggestion. And yes, I would add that more than half of the questions are below average average requirements :)

Comment: I think I was being kinda harsh (sorry Angel). Just saw one too many of these "can you solve this problem..." questions followed later with "thanks, but that's not the REAL problem..." recently :-(.

Comment: hahaha, I completely agree with what you say Ed... as I said, I didn't want to make a long question so that it would be easier to answer and read... then I would try to modify it according to my final necessities... but I am a horrible noob in awk and in programming in general, and I couldn't solve it by myself. Next time I know the lesson

Answer (score 1):

You can store the items from first file in a set, and during the iteration over second file simply check if the integer exists in that set or not.(Sets provide `O(1)` lookup, and store only unique items)

```
with open('file1') as f:
    #Store the values from file1 in a set
    data = {line.strip() for line in f}

with open('file2') as f, open('output', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
       a, b = line.split()
       if a in data: 
           #If item found in data set, then write to output file. 
           out.write(b + '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
200
201
203
204
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} {printf "%s", ($1 in map ? map[$1] RS : "")}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
replace = {}
with open('2nd') as f:
    for line in f:
        splt = line.split()
        thing = splt[0]
        new = splt[1]
        replace[thing] = new

with open('1st') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == '#':
            print line
        else:
            splt = line.split()
            thing = splt[0]
            splt[0] = replace.get(thing, thing)
            print '\t'.join(splt)  # no idea what's your real delimiter
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that **BOTH** input files are sorted, and that numbers are unique on **BOTH** first columns, this would do it without consuming the extra memory it takes loading one of the files on RAM.

```
import sys

def replace(in1, in2, out):
    for num1, num2 in (x.split() for x in in2):
        for col1 in in1:
            if col1.strip() == num1:
                out.write(num2 + '\n')
                break
        else:
            # End if in1
            break

replace(open('1st'), open('2nd'), sys.stdout)
```